# how to render array data from api?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i want to render DetectedText from api which is already in array so how can render it or what is the method to render it below is the react code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'




class Image extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { file: '', imagePreviewUrl: '', selectedOption: '', change: [], response: [], path: [], jsonData:[] };
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        var byteCode = this.state.imagePreviewUrl.substring((e.target.value).indexOf(',') + 23);

        console.log('base64 byte code substring data', byteCode);


        let url = "http://192.168.4.138/MediaAnalysisImage_Amazon/api/DetectText/DetectText"
            console.log(url);
            const data = {  "fileByte": byteCode }


            console.log(data)

            const response = axios.post(url, data)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        change: response,
                        byteArr: response.data.fileByte,
                        jsonData: response.data.jsondata.replace(/[&\/\\#+()$"~%.'*?<>{}]/g, ''),

                        path: response.data.jsondata.Confidence


                    });
                    console.log('Byte data', this.state.byteArr)
                    console.log('json detected data', response.data.jsondata.DetectedText)
                })




    }

    radioChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: e.target.value

        });

    }
    handleImageChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];


        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                file: file,
                imagePreviewUrl: reader.result



            });

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file)


    }

    render() {
        const img = "data:image/png;base64" + ',' + this.state.byteArr
        let { imagePreviewUrl } = this.state;

        let $imagePreview = null;
        if (imagePreviewUrl) {
            $imagePreview = (<img src={imagePreviewUrl} className="img-responsive imgp" />);
            console.log(imagePreviewUrl)
        } else {
            $imagePreview = (<span className="previewText">Please select an Image for Preview</span>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <h2 className="text-center heading" >Text Recognization</h2>
                <div className="container ">

                    <section className="celeb">
                        <form className="Fform bg-light mb-4">

                            <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="face" onChange={this.radioChange} />Face
                         </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="celeb" onChange={this.radioChange} />Celeb
                         </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check mb-4">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="text" onChange={this.radioChange} />Text
                         </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <input className="fileInput"
                                    type="file"
                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleImageChange(e)} class="btn btn-secondary" />
                            </div>
                            <button className="btn btn-success"
                                type="submit"
                                onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Upload Image</button>
                        </form>
                        <hr></hr>
                        <div className="row grid">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <h3>Input Image</h3>
                                {$imagePreview}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <h3>Output Image</h3>



                                <img src={img} className="img-responsive imgp" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr></hr>

                            <h4>Description </h4>
                            <table className="table table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <th ><label>Name :- </label></th>
                                    <td>{this.state.jsonData}</td>


                                </tr>
                            </table>


                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Image;
```

and below is the api return data and  adding the image of api return data  so please check that and tell me what should changes i have to make

[api return data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbCa4.png)
  just see the marked text i.e DetectedText and tell me how to render it

Comment: can u give the data u get ?

Comment: ok please check the link https://github.com/pradeepgorule/react/blob/master/error%20file

Comment: copy the data from postman then put it in ur github link. the data set u give that is not well format has so much error.

Comment: please check the link again im adding postman data

Answer (score 0):

First Use the `JSON.parse` it will convert your data yo array object then loop through all ur data and do the rest

```
var data = {
    "filename": null,
    "fileByte": "", // ur response data 
    "jsondata": "" // ur response data
}

var parseData = JSON.parse(data.jsondata)
console.log(parseData)
var DetectedText = []
for (x of parseData) {
  console.log(x) // all the data
  console.log(x.Confidence) // single one
  console.log(x.DetectedText)
  DetectedText.push(x.DetectedText)
}
console.log(DetectedText)
this.setState({dText:DetectedText })
```

and loop ur `DetectedText` inside rende
Hope it will help if anything required please inform

Comment: but display eroor  "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: below the "console.log('json detected data', response.data.jsondata.DetectedText)"

Comment: which data u parse ? `response.data.jsondata` this one ? it will not parse . remove the replace code and try plz

Comment: yeah first print the response see what data its provide if it is same as you gave me in git then parse it and do the rest

Comment: I got the data into console and display me the whole json data in console

Comment: but i want to display DetectedText in UI how Should i display will you please tell me

Comment: you can setState your the.setState({dtext: : response.DetectedText}) and call it in view like `this.state.dtext`

and please accept the  answer as it is solve and it was about render the data from api Thanks

Comment: but the data coming to me is in array so it not display and showing undefined in console

Comment: ur data is showing something like this right ?
[{
Confidence:99.80314,
DetectedText:"Hello World!",
Geometry: {...},
Id:0,
ParentId:0,
Type: {...}
}]

Comment: yes and displaying it like this                                                                            
                         for (let x of  parseData) {
                        console.log('all data', x) // all the data
                        console.log('single data', x.DetectedText)
                        const DetectedText = x.DetectedText
                        console.log('DetectedText ', DetectedText)   // single one
                    }
                    this.setState({ dText:response.DetectedText })
                    console.log('setting dtext',this.state.dText)

Comment: bro as u assign ur value to DetectedTex 
so it will be 
 this.setState({ dText:DetectedText })
please check the updated ansewr

Comment: ha i know that im updating my githu link and uplaoding my whole code into in it so please review  the code and tell me where should i change im not understand what you told me please chek the link https://github.com/pradeepgorule/react/blob/master/error%20file

Comment: bro this is beyond ur question. i am pretty sure i am solve ur question issue. so accept the anwer if it is help.
and if there is any other issue ask another question. i can not complete ur whole work
thanks